# Named arguments of a constructor in a type using F#

Tags: f#, constructor, types, arguments, named-parameters

Consider the following code:

```
type Test(a) =
  member o.A = a

let test = Test(a = cos 5.)
let test2 = Test(a = 5. |> cos) // ERROR
let test3 = Test(a = (5. |> cos))
```

Test2 line gives an error:

> The type 'bool' does not support any operators named 'Cos'

and

> The value or constructor 'a' is not defined

I understand the error message but I wonder is it not a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F# parser treats named arguments as equality test expressions; a later stage of the compiler decodes them into named arguments.  Thus it is a precedence issue as described by @desco.

Note that if you have a boolean named parameter, you can do e.g.

```
F(a = true)    // named param
F((a = true))  // compare local name 'a', then pass boolean as first arg
```

as a way to disambiguate in the rare case it is needed.

Comment: ... and `F(a = (a = true))` is possible as well. Looks kinda funny, though :)

Answer (score 5):

think it is ok, since precedence of (|>)  is lesser than (=) expression

```
Test(a = 5. |> cos)
```

is intepreted as

```
Test((a = 5.) |> cos)
```

and is this case error message is correct

Comment: But I do not think that "=" is an equal sign here, is it? What would the equal sign mean here?: Test(a = cos 5.). I would expect "=" be as in "let a = 5. |> cos" and the precedence should be accordingly. Am I wrong?

Comment: `x = y` is a boolean expression (and so is `a = 5.`) while `let x = value` binds a value.

Comment: A `=` at the top level (immediately inside the parenthesis) is interpreted as a named parameter, or field/property assignment. Any other place it is treated as an equality test.

Comment: MizardX: So if it is a field/property assignment, it should have an assignment precedence. Am I right?

Comment: @MizardX: Yes, but due to the precedence of `=`, `a = 5. |> cos` is resolved to `cos (a = 5.)` and *not* to `a = (5. |> cos)`.

Comment: @Oldrich: `=` is the bind and the comparison operator, but not assignment (which is done with `<-`). `let a = 5. |> cos` indeed binds the result to a, but `Test(a = 5. |> cos)` actually compares a to 5.0, and then would try to apply the `cos` function to the boolean result, which obviously doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mephane: I disagree. How can you compare to "a" which does not exist? From my point of view it is a binding similarly to records. Example: type Test = { a: float } let test = {a = 5. |> cos }

Comment: @Oldrich Svec: "How can you compare to "a" which does not exist?" Well, you cannot and that's precisely what the compiler tells you: "The value or constructor 'a' is not defined."

Comment: @Novox: But what I am talking about are so called "Named arguments". See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx

Comment: @Oldrich Svec: I believe I do know what you are talking about ;) By now several people have elaborated in the above comments that with `a = 5. |> cos` you are doing something different and why this is the case. If you want to pass a named parameter, you have to use parentheses in this case.

Comment: @Novox: As I understand it, "a = cos 5." is treated as a named argument and the named argument is therefore prioritized against the equality operator. "a = 5. |> cos" is on the other hand treated as the equality operator and the equality operator is thus prioritized against the named argument. I find that inconsistent and confusing. But probably it is the only way how it can be implemented...